# Why does the entry widget not display text when I use state='readonly'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to create a table to display text using entry widgets. I've written code that work,s however when I try to add `state=readonly` it simply does not display the text.

So when I run this code, it works fine but the entry widgets are editable:

```
# Python program to create a table

from tkinter import *


class Table:

    def __init__(self, root):

        # code for creating table
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                self.e = Entry(root, width=20, fg='blue',
                               font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'), state='readonly')

                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.e.insert(END, lst[i][j])

            # take the data


lst = [(1, 'Raj', 'Mumbai', 19),
       (2, 'Aaryan', 'Pune', 18),
       (3, 'Vaishnavi', 'Mumbai', 20),
       (4, 'Rachna', 'Mumbai', 21),
       (5, 'Shubham', 'Delhi', 21)]

# find total number of rows and
# columns in list
total_rows = len(lst)
total_columns = len(lst[0])

# find total number of rows and
# columns in list
root = Tk()
t = Table(root)
root.mainloop()
```

However, whenever I add `state='readonly'` inside the brackets of `self.e`, the table just doesn't display text anymore. Does anyone know why this happens?

I'm using python 3.6 by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the state is `readonly`, the widget cannot be edited. That means that any call to `insert` will fail. That's how it's designed to work.

If you want the widget to be read-only, set the state *after* inserting the text.